# Fetching API in my react app doesnt work, Unhandled Rejection (TypeError)

Tags: reactjs

I am tryig to call an internal flask API function through my reactapplication as follow:

```
export default function ThermoBreastCancerIntroPage({ ...rest }) {
  const [is_logged_in, set_is_logged_in] = useState('false');
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/is_logged_in/').then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        const {name} = data.results[0];
        set_is_logged_in(name.res);
        console.log(is_logged_in);
      });
  }, []);
```

The flask API returns responses as follow:

```
return jsonify({'res':False})
```

But I am getting below error at browser:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/ThermoAnalyser/material-kit-pro-react-v1.9.0/src/views/LandingPage/ThermoBreastCancerPage.js:37
  34 | window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  35 | document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  36 | fetch('http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/is_logged_in/').then(results => results.json())
> 37 |   .then(data => {
     | ^  38 |     const {name} = data.results[0];
  39 |     set_is_logged_in(name.res);
  40 |     console.log(is_logged_in);
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Something in the returned Promise chain from the fetch is returning a rejection or throwing an error. You can try catching it. Ah, you added the error, just check that `data.results` is an array with at least length 1.

Comment: Can you try and print the value of results like so `fetch('http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/is_logged_in/').then(results => console.log(results))`

Comment: I am using flask-cors inside my flask application..the log for results is ""Response {type: "cors", url: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/is_logged_in/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}..and its json property has length of 0

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Something in your promise chain is either returning a promise rejection or throwing an error, either of which should be caught and handled.

`fetch`

- Returns a rejected promise for any network errors and cancelled requests
- Returns a resolved promise for all other requests, so you need to check the `ok` status first

`results.json`

- Returns a resolved promise if successful in parsing JSON response
- Can reject on any processing errors

Your handling logic

- If `data.results` is either *not* an array, or an array of length 0, then trying to access properties of undefined will also throw an error

## Suggestion

1. Check for a successful fetch request
2. Add a `catch` block to the promise chain

code

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/is_logged_in/')
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    const {name} = data.results[0]; // <-- if this throws, is ok since now caught
    set_is_logged_in(name.res);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    // any other error handling and accounting the app/component needs
  });
```

## Second minor issue

```
set_is_logged_in(name.res);
console.log(is_logged_in);
```

Enqueued react state updates are asynchronous and processed *between* render cycles, so trying to log the "updated" state right after enqueueing it will only log the state from the *current* render cycle, not the *next* state you are expecting. You should use an effect to log when the state value updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(is_logged_in);
}, [is_logged_in]);
```